# What is the difference between a method with access modifiers and a method without?

Tags: c#

I can not understand the concept of a method that doesn't have access modifiers. What are they for? What is the use to not put access modifiers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A class member without access modifier is private. I.e., it is only visible within the class itself.

Example:

```
public class Test
{
    public void Hello()
    {
        Print("Hello");
        Print(" ");
        Print("World");
    }

    void Print(string s)
    {
        Console.Write(s);
    }
}
```

In this example the `Print` method is not public, but can be called from within a method that is `public`.

```
var test = new Test();
test.Hello(); // Works.
test.Print("bye"); // Not possible - compiler error!
```

I prefer to explicitly declare the members as private and to write the `private` modifier, but this is up to you:

```
private void Print(string s)
{
    Console.Write(s);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A method doesn't have access modifiers written means it has a default modifier: private

Comment: this can't be right. Private can't always be the default.

Comment: Always, except microsoft changes the standard some day. https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/blob/master/spec/basic-concepts.md#declared-accessibility

Comment: This standard will never change, as this would be a major braking change in C#.

Answer (score 0):

In .NET, methods have default access modifier so you don't always have to specify them explicitly but it's considered a very bad practice not to explicitly specify them. See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/access-modifiers) for the default access modifier for different methods.

Answer (score 0):

All types and type members have an accessibility level, which controls how they can be used, the following tutorial may help you to get a better grasp of C# modifiers.

[C# Programming Guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/access-modifiers)

Answer (score 0):

if there is no access modifier written with a method it means its private by default
This is a public Mehtod

```
public void Yourmethod()
{
}
```

This is a private Method by default

```
void Yourmethod()
{
}
```